# c++ restart service in windows as admin

Tags: c++, windows, api, service

I'm trying to restart the "postgres" service in my C++ application on windows 10 but I having some problems with access rights( my guess ). I have tried running the code as a domain user that has local admin rights and as a local administrator but none of these seem to work. I can restart the service manually via the services.msc. The code fails already at OpenSCManager which returns NULL. I have also tried other access rights but then OpenService fails. This is my code

```
auto showError = []()
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << GetLastError();

    qDebug() << "Restart PostgreSQL service failed : " << QString::fromStdString( os.str());
};

SERVICE_STATUS Status;

SC_HANDLE SCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS );

if(SCManager == NULL)
    showError();

SC_HANDLE SHandle = OpenService(SCManager, L"postgres", SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS );

if(SHandle == NULL)
    showError();

if(!ControlService(SHandle, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &Status))
    showError();

do
{
    QueryServiceStatus(SHandle, &Status);
    qDebug() << "Checking Service Status...\n";
}while(Status.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOPPED);


if(!StartService(SHandle, 0, NULL))
    showError();

std::cin.sync();
std::cin.ignore();

CloseServiceHandle(SCManager);
CloseServiceHandle(SHandle);
```

Comment: What is the result of `GetLastError`? Is it access denied, or something else?

Comment: error 5 Access Denied

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for too many permissions that you don't actually need. Don't use `SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS` and `SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS`. NEVER ask for more permissions than you really need.  All you really need in this situation are `SC_MANAGER_CONNECT` for `OpenSCManager()`, and `SERVICE_STOP`, `SERVICE_START` and `SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS` for `OpenService()`.

If you still get an "Access Denied" error after fixing this in your code, then the service really requires your account to have permissions to start/stop the service.  So either run your code in an elevated admin process, or at least configure your user account with the appropriate permissions.

And FYI, your query loop is too minimalistic. You are ignoring the `Status` that `ControlService()` reports, and you are not accounting for the possibility of the service entering a pending state, or refusing to stop. You need to check the initial status, only if it is in a pending state than enter the query loop until it is no longer in a pending state, then check the final state for stopped before then attempting to start the service. Also be sure to check if the service hangs while trying to stop it.

See [Stopping a Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/stopping-a-service) on MSDN.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
auto showError = []()
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    qDebug() << "Restart PostgreSQL service failed. Error: " << err << "\n";
};

SERVICE_STATUS Status;

SC_HANDLE SCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
if (!SCManager)
{
    showError();
    return;
}

SC_HANDLE SHandle = OpenService(SCManager, L"postgres", SERVICE_STOP | SERVICE_START | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
if (!SHandle)
{
    showError();
    CloseServiceHandle(SCManager);
    return;
}

if (!QueryServiceStatus(SHandle, &Status))
{
    showError(); 
    CloseServiceHandle(SHandle);
    CloseServiceHandle(SCManager);
    return;
}

if (Status.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOPPED)
{
    qDebug() << "Stopping PostgreSQL service...\n";

    if (!ControlService(SHandle, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &Status))
    {
        showError();
        CloseServiceHandle(SHandle);
        CloseServiceHandle(SCManager);
        return;
    }

    DWORD dwStartTime = GetTickCount();
    DWORD dwTimeout = 30000; // 30-second time-out
    DWORD dwWaitTime;

    while (Status.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    {
        qDebug() << "Waiting for PostgreSQL service to stop...\n";

        dwWaitTime = Status.dwWaitHint / 10;
        if (dwWaitTime < 1000)
            dwWaitTime = 1000;
        else if (dwWaitTime > 10000)
            dwWaitTime = 10000;

        Sleep(dwWaitTime);

        if (!QueryServiceStatus(SHandle, &Status))
        {
            showError();
            CloseServiceHandle(SHandle);
            CloseServiceHandle(SCManager);
            return;
        }

        if (Status.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
            break;

        if (GetTickCount() - dwStartTime > dwTimeout)
        {
            qDebug() << "Stop of PostgreSQL service timed out.\n";
            CloseServiceHandle(SHandle);
            CloseServiceHandle(SCManager);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (Status.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOPPED)
    {
        qDebug() << "Restart PostgreSQL service failed. Service did not stop.\n";
        CloseServiceHandle(SHandle);
        CloseServiceHandle(SCManager);
        return;
    }

    qDebug() << "PostgreSQL service stopped successfully.\n";
}

if (!StartService(SHandle, 0, NULL))
    showError();

CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
```

Comment: thanks for correcting the last part of the code but I still get an access denied error, can you tell me how or where to find info on one of the solutions that you suggest?

Comment: As I said in my answer: "*If you still get an "Access Denied" error after fixing this in your code, then the service really requires your account to have permissions to start/stop the service.*"  So this becomes a permissions issue, not a coding issue. If you want to solve this in code, you could separate your restart code into its own function, and then if it fails with "access denied" and you are not already running elevated then use `ShellExecute/Ex("runas")` to run a new elevated copy of your EXE passing it a command-line parameter that tells it to only call that function and then exit.

Comment: I tried reading some articles on the net but I don't understand why my account can restart the service manually but not via the code.
Would the ShellExecute/Ex("runas")  not trigger a uac?

Comment: Obviously the native SCM app is running with a user account that has more permissions than your user account has when running your app. So figure out why your user account is lacking the permissions you want. Or just make sure your app is run as an elevated admin user to begin with. And yes, `ShellExecute/Ex("runas")` would trigger UAC, that is the whole point - to start a new process that has elevated permissions when started by a process that is lacking them.

Comment: this seems to work 
`CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"Administrator",L"MyPC",L"Password",LOGON_WITH_PROFILE,NULL,szCmdline,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &processInfo)`
So with my current account which is a domain account and a member of local administrator it does not work, but with the builtin administrator account it works. Can you or somebody else explain to me why it works with my domain account when I restart the service from the services.msc without any uac or elevation that I can observe